# How do I get Mediapipe landmark indices?

Tags: mediapipe

I am new to mediapipe and face detection and I am trying to extract the landmarks of the lip region of the face. It was quite easy in dlib as the landmarks were kind of continuous, but in media pipe they seem quite random and I cannot get the desired landmarks.
For example in dlib the landmark indices of the left eye are : [37,38,39,40,41,42]
How do I get the same for mediapipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but Mediapipe use the same face mesh as sceneform or ARCore. Here is [the link](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/assets/canonical_face_mesh.fbx) to the original face mesh.

Beside, here is [the close version](https://github.com/ManuelTS/augmentedFaceMeshIndices) which you can use to choose your landmark index.

So basically, mediapipe results will be a list of 468 landmarks, you can access to those landmark by its index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any mapping of MediaPipe landmarks to Dlib landmarks. You will have to run an image and plot the landmarks with their indexes. Because you have a lot of landmarks I recommend you to run a very large image so you will be able to see the landmarks indexes.